# what is zero value of reflect.Value in golang

Tags: go, reflection

In golang reflect package, reflect.value.IsValid has those comments:

IsValid reports whether v represents a value. It returns false if v is the zero Value. If IsValid returns false, all other methods except String panic. Most functions and methods never return an invalid value. If one does, its documentation states the conditions explicitly.

Read above, i am very confused. i don't know what is zero value of reflect.Value and use it call  isValid get false.

I write some code to test:

```
var haha *int
fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(haha).IsValid()) //true
var hehe interface{}
fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(hehe).IsValid() //false
```

Comment: You just presented an example that shows taking the ValueOf an empty interface returns the zero value. What is it you're confused about?

Comment: Any value in Go has a "zero value". This is 0 for numbers, "" for strings, nil for pointers and so on. Any type. So the type `reflect.Value` has a zero value (whatever that is). That's what the documentation is talking about. Stay away from package reflect until you are very familiar with Go.

Comment: @Volker In my work, i need to use reflect to implement my project. Using reflect pkg is very danger, but i want to try and learn. i familiar with golang ,but i don't use reflect pkg in common developing

Answer (score 0):

A zero value is the default initialization value that is written to the memory address when no explicit initialization is provided. Tesing if v is a zero value is, in fact, testing if you have initialized v.

`var haha *int` returns true because haha is a pointer and cannot be created with an rational "default zero value", otherwise it would point to a random address in your memory and could have dangerous side effects. Pointers are nil when they are created, when other data types will have an actual value.

On the other hand, the zero value of `var hehe interface{}` is a nil *int, which is an actual entity.

Comment: The explanation you give might be a bit misleading: Go does not distinguish between "just declared" and "initialized". Any declared Go value will be initialized to the zero value. The pointer and empty interface example behave totally identical, both are set to nil by the compiler. The real reason why the hehe example behaves differently is described in the documentation of reflect.ValueOf: ValueOf looks _inside_ the stuff you pass: For the haha case the `i` in ValueOf contains a non-nil interface{} containing a nil *int. The haha case is explained by the last sentence: i==nil.

Comment: @Volker your anwser is very clearly. i read the doc of reflect.ValueOf, then i know, zero value is constructed by reflect.ValueOf(nil). haha is pointer, it's point to nil value.  hehe is nil and it's container value is nil. So, when i call reflect.ValueOf on haha, it's return a reflect.Ptr type data. but  for hehe, it's return a reflect.Invalid type data. thanks